# Python - storing and changing variable in json

Tags: python, json, discord

So I tried store 'number' in JSON, but I still don't know how I can update it. It should look something like on command it read number from JSON (some code) and on the end it's adding 1 to this number and when you use again this command it will show number increased by 1.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your JSON data as a Python dictionary. If your data is stored as a JSON, then you can convert it to a dictionary with the `json` library.

```py
from json import loads

# Data as JSON string
json_data = '{"number": 0}'

# Convert to a dictionary
python_dictionary = loads(json_data)
```

Afterwards, you can alter the JSON (now dictionary) values by calling them changing them in the dictionary.

```py
# Increment
python_dictionary["number"] += 1
```

Finally, when you need to use the data in JSON format again, you can convert it back like so:

```py
# Convert back to json
from json import dumps
new_json = dumps(python_dictionary)
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck!